# On second click disable all clicks for two seconds?

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of divs where class is "box" and would like for the user to be able to click on two of them, then have to wait two seconds before being able to click on another one.

This is as far as I've gotten...

```
var clickNumber = 0;

$(".box").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    switch (clickNumber){
        case 0:
            clickNumber++;
            break;
        case 1:
            setTimeout(function() {
                //disable click for class "box"
        }, 2000);
            clickNumber = 0;
            break;
    }
});
```

A more complete example...

http://jsfiddle.net/wZP6J/

Thank you!

Comment: Using setTimeout for this is overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable to track if clicks should be allowed, like so:

```
var clickNumber = 0,
    clicksAllowed = true;

$(".box").click(function () {
    if(clicksAllowed){
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
        switch (clickNumber){
            case 0:
                clickNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                clicksAllowed = false;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    //disable click for class "box"
                    clicksAllowed = true;
                }, 2000);
                clickNumber = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zfta/).

Answer (score 3):

[**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZP6J/3/).

Simply store the unix epoch timestamp, then compare it to the last one. If it's been more than 2 seconds, then do whatever you need to do. No need for setting a timeout.

```
;(function() {
    var clickNumber = 0;
    var lastClickTime = 0;

    $(".box").click(function () {
        var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

        if ((seconds - lastClickTime) > 2) {
            $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
            clickNumber++;
            lastClickTime = seconds;
        }
    });
})();
```

Also, notice I have used a closure to keep my relevant variables out of the global scope to keep them from being polluted.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference of the collection of "boxes" and enable/disable them in the switch statement:

```
var clickNumber = 0;
var boxes = $('.box');

boxes.click(function () {

    if (clickNumber == 1)
    {
        return; // just in case ;)
    }

    $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');

    switch (clickNumber){
        case 0:
            clickNumber++;
            break;
        case 1:
            // disable boxes
            boxes.prop('disabled', 'disabled');

            setTimeout(function() {
                //enabled boxes after 2 seconds
                boxes.prop('disabled', '');
                clickNumber = 0;
            }, 2000);

            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as [working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wZP6J/1/):

```
var clickNumber = 0;    
$(".box").click(function () {    
    switch (clickNumber) {
        case 0:
            $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
            clickNumber++;
            break;
        case 1:
            setTimeout(function () {
                clickNumber = 0;
            }, 2000);
            clickNumber++;
            break;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go ...

```
var clickNumber = 0;

$(".box").on('click', boxClick);

function boxClick() {
    clickNumber += 1;
    $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    if(clickNumber == 2) {
        $(".box").off();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.box').on('click', boxClick);
            clickNumber = 0;
        },2000);
    }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wZP6J/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JQRMS/)

```
var clickNumber = 0;

function disableClick() {
    // Disable click event for now
    $(".box").unbind('click');

    // Turn on click after timeout
    setTimeout(enableClick, 2000);
}

function enableClick() {
    $(".box").click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
        switch (clickNumber) {
            case 0:
                clickNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                disableClick();
                clickNumber = 0;
                break;
        }
    });
}

enableClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wZP6J/5/)**</kbd>

```
function clicking(){
     $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
     $(".box").off('click', clicking);
     setTimeout(function(){
        $(".box").on('click',clicking);
     },2000);
}

$(".box").on('click', clicking);
```

Comment: @crush my obsession with setTimeout looks like your obsession with timestamps 8) kidding you have a nice example. But my example shows EXACTLY how to disable something for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

even you don't need to have clickNumber Count

```
var f1 = function(){
  $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
   $(".box").unbind('click');
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $(".box").click(f1);
            }, 2000);
}
$(".box").click(f1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wZP6J/6/

Answer (score 0):

I there! Well I got a solution for you based on the code you gave me (that way you don't need to change much).

Take a look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/NAGKk/

```
var clickNumber = 0;
$(".box").click(function () {
if(clickNumber<2)
    $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    switch (clickNumber){
        case 0:
            clickNumber++;
            break;
        case 1:
            clickNumber++;
            setTimeout(function() {
                clickNumber = 0;
            }, 2000);
            break;
    }
});
```

The main idea of the setTimeout is that after some time it triggers something you put inside (you already know this), but what you must keep in mind is that the javascript keeps running (otherwise some websites would freeze for with a timeout). This solution just uses your var clickNumber and blocks the click effect if the person clicked more than twice. The setTimeout will trigger a reset on clickNumber after 2 seconds.

Hope it helps

Comment: Why use setTimeout at all?

Comment: True, there's other ways to do it. I just went with the given code and tried to show how it could be handled with the setTimeout ^^